# "Unrecognized database format" and "Inconsistent State" format on back end of a split database

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010, database-administration

So I have the be of a small Access database on the network drive with 10-15 users on front ends at any one time. Today users got an "Unrecognized database format" error.

[image: Error fe]

When I checked out the be I found an "Inconsistent State" error. Luckily I had a recent backup and Windows was able to restore it anyway.

[image: Error be]

The only other trouble like this I've had was with the fe, I needed to decomplile and recompile.

In my research it looked like most people experiencing this error were not splitting their database.

Is there something like that I need to do to the be?

Comment: Have you been doing your occasional `Compact and Repair`s to the backend?

Comment: Yes. It usually seem too throw the error when I'm running  a query that moves a lot of data. Happens more on my working copy of the be than the live version, and definitely happens more when I'm through the VPN.